# Controlling child component width within parent's dynamic width in React with TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

I'm working on a React project with TailwindCSS and encountered an issue that I'm struggling to resolve. In my project, I have a rich text editor that allows users to create HTML tables with resizable columns. The problem is that when these tables are resized to a considerable width, they extend beyond the boundaries of their parent component, which, in turn, disrupts the layout of the entire page. However, this issue doesn't occur on mobile devices, where the text editor remains within the parent component's width. This is because there's no sidebar with "position: fixed", and the layout doesn't use "margin-left" based on the width of the sidebar.

I need help to ensure that the text editor's width stays within the specified layout and doesn't extend beyond its parent's dynamic "w-full" width.

To illustrate the issue, I've created a simplified example on CodeSandbox, which you can access through this link: [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-smoke-rk5955?file=/src/App.tsx:56-678). This CodeSandbox represents a simplified version of my problem. In reality, I'm using the Tiptap text editor with resizable text areas.

For your convenience, here's the code snippet from the example:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="flex w-full bg-slate-50 relative">
      <div className="w-40 border border-red-500 fixed top-0 left-0 bottom-0">
        Sidebar
      </div>
      <div className="ml-40 flex w-full p-4">
        <div className="w-full border border-blue-500 min-h-[90px]">
          <textarea
            style={{
              // maxWidth: "inherit" // doesn't help,
              maxWidth: "initial" // also doesn't help
            }}
            className="resize-x max-w-full border border-green-500"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```